# C# Closing SoundPlayer on FormClosing

Tags: c#

I've created a bool value named musiclose. I'm planning if this musiclose value is true, player will close, else it will continue playing.

`public static bool musiclose;`

Timer code is below:

```
timer1.Interval = 1000;
timer1.Start();
```

Here is the code:

```
public void timer3_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SoundPlayer player = new SoundPlayer(@"C:\Path\To\intro.wav");

    if (musiclose)
    {
        player.Stop();
        musiclose = false;
    }
}
```

How can I do that??

Comment: There is something in programming called events. The code for the event will run everytime the "event" happens. In your case the form closing... Just put the the player.Stop() on the event and no need for musiclose.                           https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.closing(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: OK. I'm understand. But my form is included a loading page. And this music isn't run on loading page. If loading is completed musiclose value is setting 1. In short string is needed .It's not. (If your comment is valid on my condition, sorry I'm starter on this thing.)

Comment: Not clear why are you need a timer to stop player? Usually you have a button which the user would click to stop playing.

Answer (score 1):

1) Do not recreate SoundPlayer instance everytime inside timer3_Tick() event. Create a global instance of SoundPlayer.

2) Implement form closing  event, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formclosing(v=vs.110).aspx

3) In the close event,

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(Object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    player.Stop();
    player.Dispose();
}
```